# Java + spring - central way of persisting historical events to a database log

Tags: java, database, spring, annotations, history

I have a small app using the following technology stack - java, spring, resteasy, hibernate, oracle db.
This app is a type of translator - it takes incoming HTTP message from a source, processes them and forwards them on to a destination.

I want to keep a persistent database log of all the messages that have passed through this app with columns such as message_type, date_received, date_processed, status, error_message (if there was an error), etc.

What is the best way to have a central place that "chronicles" these messages? I want this to happen on successful processing, as well as on failed messages without having to put code in too many places. I want something clean, maybe annotation based even.. since I'm using spring.

Appreciate any ideas and suggestions.

Comment: you could combine  underdogs idea with the typical ELK stack: http://logstash.net/ https://www.elastic.co/ https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana

Answer (score 3):

You can use AOP & apply it on the methods processing your input messages. Write a separate advice for sending the log messages to the database. This approach would be clean. You don't have to litter your logging code across the app, just write it in a class & apply on the methods at runtime.

Comment: I like that idea, it's exactly the type of thing I was looking for... one thing though, I need to pass the details of the message that was processed to the generic aspect method that will do the logging - is that possible?

Comment: I found some examples that do what I need. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by making use of the logger extensions.

For example if you are using log4j there are appenders that help you write to different resources.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

In your case you need to add a DatabaseAppender that will log to your defined table in the database. The flexible configuration in Spring & AOP can be wired to your spring bean.

Comment: Here's an example: Log4j, logback respectively :                                [Log4j](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/08/how-to-create-logs-in-database-using-jdbcappender-in-log4j/)                                                      [Logback](http://learningviacode.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/writing-logs-to-database.html)